# Run a gui based application on a remote Linux machine using telnet

Tags: linux, user-interface, ubuntu, telnet

I need to run a gui-based application on a remote PC to which I am connected over telnet. The remote PC runs **Linux Ubuntu 18.04**

To figure out the screen, I run the following command on the remote machine:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

which gave me **:1** as result.

Then I run the program on the remote machine from my client (over telnet) using:

```
DISPLAY=:1 application_name
```

The program started correctly (since, in addition to the GUI, it prints some things on the command line) but the GUI didn't show up. But, if I run my app directly on the remote machine, everything is fine.

As a test, I tried to run firefox browser on an another machine (always through telnet) with the following command:

```
DISPLAY=:0 firefox
```

and it worked. **Note:** on the other machine the output of echo $DISPLAY was :0. Furthermore, I could not test my app on the second machine.

It seems that there are different settings between the two machines since what I'm trying to do works on a machine, but not on the other.

Do you have any idea of what type of setting should I check?

Comment: You're actually using telnet? In this day and age? Use ssh, and its X forwarding.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a requirement I was given.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run your application on the first remote machine but with DISPLAY=:0 instead of :1?

What is the error message you get from application when you started application in the first case ("DISPLAY=:1 app_name").